# Sombody injected some links in the wordpress site. What could be the origin? And how did it happen?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, security, code-injection

A site of mine (maximumsportperformance.com) has this script at the top:

```
<div onmousemove="this.style.display='block'" id=xtg style="DISPLAY: none" onmouseout="this.style.display='none'"> <a href="http://www.watcheslaw.com/">replica watches</a>  <a href="http://www.penwatches.org/">fake watches</a>   <a href="http://www.watcheslaw.com/">replica watches</a><a href="http://www.penwatches.org/">fake watches</a </div>
```

I tried to find the origin but I couldnt find any in header, footer or any plugin as well as theme files.

Another thing is that this script is showing in Source code of IE only but not in Firebug in Mozilla since I backed up database and reinstalled the WP on host.

I googled about the same problem and found these sites with same problem

lawak.com

webdeveloper.net.au

hyderalaska.com

All sites have the same kind of links wrapped up in div with js.

Please help me to find the flaw and loophole for securing it from future threats.

Comment: Do you have the latest WP version installed? Are you using 3rd party plugins?

Comment: You may find the answers at the [securing wordpress question](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25189/users-often-say-my-website-is-infected-but-cant-find-any-evidence-of-this) useful.

Answer (score 3):

It is a rather clever hack to try to boost their Google ranking. Fortunately, if that's all that was left behind it's relatively harmless to your users besides destroying a bit of your SEO efforts.

Personally, I would go scorched earth on that. Once someone broke in, there's no way of knowing if they left a backdoor somewhere that would let them back in at a later date*

Start fresh, re-install plugins from their online source,restore the content. 
Then, run through the steps in this guide to harden the install against further attacks like this one:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress

* Okay, so actually there are ways of knowing if files were modified using cryptographic hashes. There's even a nice Linux utility the NSA sponsored that will do this and spit out a report of the changes. However, this requires care and feeding, so it's probably not a great use of your time.

Comment: Thanks Dave. Actually that re installation worked. But thanks for your efforts, I will keep these things in mind.